# linking libphonenumber/C++

Tags: c++, libphonenumber

I am trying to statically link my project to a fresh libphonenumber/cpp build (release 8.12.56), and get lots of linker errors involving abseil. Here are the first two:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../libphonenumber/cpp/build/libphonenumber.a(phonenumberutil.cc.o): in function `absl::lts_20220623::hash_internal::MixingHashState::MixingHashState()':
phonenumberutil.cc:(.text._ZN4absl12lts_2022062313hash_internal15MixingHashStateC2Ev[_ZN4absl12lts_2022062313hash_internal15MixingHashStateC5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::hash_internal::MixingHashState::kSeed'
/usr/bin/ld: ../libphonenumber/cpp/build/libphonenumber.a(phonenumberutil.cc.o): in function `absl::lts_20220623::hash_internal::MixingHashState::CombineContiguousImpl(unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::integral_constant<int, 8>)':
phonenumberutil.cc:(.text._ZN4absl12lts_2022062313hash_internal15MixingHashState21CombineContiguousImplEmPKhmSt17integral_constantIiLi8EE[_ZN4absl12lts_2022062313hash_internal15MixingHashState21CombineContiguousImplEmPKhmSt17integral_constantIiLi8EE]+0x56): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::hash_internal::MixingHashState::CombineLargeContiguousImpl64(unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
```

Somewhat similarly named functions do appear in libphonenumber.a, but apparently they do not match. libphonenumber_test runs successfully.

The last version of libphonenumber to successfully link with my project is 8.12.39.

My build environment is out-of-the-box debian buster with a the required libraries (as specified in the README) and default-jre-headless installed. I tried compiling with C++11 and C++17 standard. I also tried a few intermediate versions of libphonenumber, with no success.

g++ version: g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
cmake version: cmake version 3.13.4

Comment: Obvious question: are you linking against abseil?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher; rather obvious, indeed. I was under the impression that most if not all abseil functions are already collected in libphonenumber. While abseil is built, I don't see a dedicated static abseil library being created.

Comment: A static library is just a zip file of file objects. You might need to link against Abseil from the binary that uses your library. Is Abseil from the system or you hand compile it?

Comment: the libphonenumber build process downloads abseil & builds it, but I don't see a dedicated abseil library being created.